# SELECT INTO with modifing the data definition of the target column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `SELECT INTO` statement :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales.MyOrders;
SELECT orderid, custid, orderdate, shipcountry, freight
INTO Sales.MyOrders
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE shipcountry = N'Norway';
```

The `orderid` column in `Sales.Orders` has an identity property. I want to remove identity property for the target column and make it not nullable. How can I achieve this in my previous statement ?

Comment: Please, provide the tables definition. Are you looking for `IDENTITY_INSERT`? Or maybe altering the table? As it is it's not clear to me.

Comment: A related bug: [SELECT INTO with IDENTITY column in expression is handled inconsistently](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32905954-select-into-with-identity-column-in-expression-is). It appears that the sample code to reproduce the problem was eliminated when Microsoft Connect folded up its tent. So it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below :

```
SELECT
ISNULL(orderid + 0, -1) AS orderid, -- get rid of identity property
-- make column NOT NULL
custid, orderdate, shipcountry, freight
INTO Sales.MyOrders
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE shipcountry = N'Norway';
```